# How to create feedback loops in RX without Subjects?

Tags: java, loops, rx-java, reactive-programming, feedback

**Update**: I've completely reformulated the question and the code in response to Alexei Kaigorodov's answer and it's not corresponding until he updates it.

There are some existing questions here on SO and articles on internet generally regarding how to create some kind of feedback loop in RX flow. Most of them are answered by shifting the point of view on the underlying problem resulting in different design of the flow which could be handled by existing operators. For example:

- True feedback loop can be achieved by using `Subject`s, but it's discouraged because it sacrifices functional purity and it's advantages.
- Feedback loop is often just a disguise for a state, which can be maintained by `scan` operator.
- Feedback loop may be just a disguise for nesting stream contexts, which can be achieved by nesting `flatMap`s

From time to time I however encounter a problem which I think is a fundamental feedback loop which should be modeled as such so I have been thinking about it a lot and I have got curious about the general question: is true feedback loop at least theoreticaly compatible with RX model given it's functional purity and one-way nature? Or do I need to move to general data flow library in that case, as Alexei suggest?

I have tried many interesting hacks how to smuggle feedback into RX flow. The best I can do, apart from using `Subject`s, is to use `defer` operator like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // simulate hot observable emitting external events
        final Observable<Message> sourceStream = Observable
                .interval(200, MILLISECONDS)
                .map(signal -> new SourceMessage(signal));
        
        // feedback needs to be referencable through final variable in the
        // next step, but we also can't define it yet, so prepare a mutable
        // container for it
        final MutableObservableHolder feedback = new MutableObservableHolder();
        
        // accumulate source and feedback messages in the state
        final Observable<State> stateStream = sourceStream
                .mergeWith(Observable.defer(() -> feedback.get()))
                .scan(new State(), (state, message) -> state.update(message))
                .share(); // prevents infinite subscription loops
        
        feedback.set(stateStream
                .flatMap(state -> {
                    if (state.isAddNextSumAgainWithDelay()) {
                        return stateStream
                                .take(1)
                                .map(nextState -> new FeedbackMessage(nextState.getPayload()))
                                .delay(100, MILLISECONDS);
                    } else {
                        return Observable.empty();
                    }
                }));
        
        Disposable subscription = stateStream
            .take(10)
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
        
        while (!subscription.isDisposed()) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

(Whole runnable project is published at https://github.com/calaveraInfo/literate-octo-happiness)

What is interesting is that it's pretty difficult to distill the essence that prevents solving some problem by usual RX operators. The above example comes pretty close to being the most orthogonal I can come up with: Sum upstream message's payloads and produce stream of intermediate sums and in some cases add the sum itself to the sum, but do it as a separate step (I add delay do highlight it). Even this could however be implemented with some kind of scanFlatMap or flatMapScan operator if it could be added to RX.

Is my implementation of feedback loop safe or is it a dangerous hack with landmines that can blow up my face under some circumstances? Why is there no flatMapScan operator, if it seems so fundamental, and is it a good idea to request it? Are there some inherent limits of what RX can model or is every problem always just question of right operators?

Update: By flatMapScan I mean a possibility to do flatMap and scan as a single step. The motivation is that when they are two different operators, their combined functionality is reduced a bit in both cases: 1. .flatMap().scan() can expand each upstream message into stream which is then scannned, but the flatMap can't use the scan state to decide how to expand the message and 2. in .scan().flatMap() the expansion can be based on the scan state, but the expanded stream won't be scanned.

I'm however not sure how the API for that might look since it would need to juggle several things at once.

Comment: What is the dataflow you try to achieve here? It's not so clear from the code example to me. Sometimes a flow similar to feedback loops can be achieved via [`expand`](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaExtensions#flowabletransformersexpand) but generally we suggest those points you already listed. Also I don't see what behavior or pattern you mean by `flatMapScan`.

Comment: Free text description of the code is in the paragraph bellow the code, starting with "Sum upstream message's payloads..." I'm not sure if you are asking to explain it more than that or if you just overlooked it. I've added explanation what I mean by flatMapScan which also may help to understand the code. I'll look at expand for this particular case, but I would be glad for any insight on the general feedback loop question or any of the particular questions in the last paragraph.

Comment: Expand operator is interesting but it's not applicable for this case, I think. I have added a link to the whole runnable example project, that should clear it up.

Comment: I checked the full example and it doesn't work because of `refCount(2)` would never get to a second observer. You can make it work by using `ConnectableObservable` and issue `connect` after all the setup and before the sleep. Overall, the setup is risky of losing items due to the `isAddNextSumAgainWithDelay` path triggering another subscription that may not get the right item. Instead, the best way would be to use a `Subject` that you can submit `Observable`s from within `scan`.

Comment: As for `flatMapScan`, such feedback loops are non-intuitive in general because of when and what is supposed to be expanded and how one would control that. This makes it not suitable to be a standard RxJava operator.

Comment: Oh, I've got unsaved file with some experiments when I commited the example, there should have been just share instead of publish refcount, then it works even without connect, I fixed it. Regarding isAddNextSumAgainWithDelay you are right, I haven't realized this discrepancy when I simplified my real case to this example, however in my real case your warning actually doesn't matter, it doesn't have to be immediate next sum, just some reasonably close. What I get from your answer is that you don't see any fundamental problem with this approach. Shame it's just a comment and not answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks cryptic. Even if you manage to make it work, it will remain difficult to maintain. Rx and Nio2 use different models of asynchronous computations, so using Rx with Nio2 only complicates programming.

I propose either to use pure Nio2, or use my asynchronous library [df4j](https://github.com/akaigoro/df4j/tree/API-7), which has adapters both to Nio2 and rx-java2.